# MySQL: Convert minutes into hours and minutes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL database. One of it's table(table name is places) has a column named duration.
I have separated the duration column in to hours and minutes.

```
|--------------
|Duration
|--------------
|Hours |mins
---------------
| 1    | 30
| 1    | 40
| 0    | 30
| 3    | 40
----------------------
Total   | 5    | 140
```

But when I get total of this values it gives 5 in hours column
and 140 in mins column
But I want to have 7 in hours column and 20 in minites column

My query is

```
$query3a = mysql_query("select SUM(hours) AS Totalhours, SUM(mins) AS Totalmins  from places");
while ($query4a = mysql_fetch_array($query3a))

enter code here

echo "<tr bgcolor='#87CEFA'><td>Total</td><td></td><td>".$query4a['Totaldistance']."&nbsp";
echo "Km";
echo "</td><td>".$query4a['Totalhours']."&nbsp";
echo "hrs";
echo "</td><td>".$query4a['Totalmins']."&nbsp";
echo "mins";
```

Comment: Don't have separate columns

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6add7/2 . Sqlfiddle has an annoying 'feature' of formatting times and dates, but you should get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum, and convert every 60 minutes to an hour:

```
SELECT SUM(hours) + SUM(mins) DIV 60 AS Totalhours, 
       SUM(mins) MOD 60 AS Totalmins  
FROM   places
```

Answer (score 0):

Add hours and minutes in  term of hours to get total hours
add minutes and get reminder of it to get total minutes

so your sql query should be like

SELECT SUM(hours) + SUM(mins) / 60 as TotalHours, SUM(mins) % 60 as TotalMins FROM places